# ASP.NET MVC - Routing Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, url-routing

This is the URL in question, that causes all of my images to break.

```
http://www.foo.com/payment/receipt/stapia.gutierrez/201110040000034
```

All of my content (images and whatnot) is declared in my _Layout.cshtml file. I believe this is an issue with my routing.

Here are the relevant parts of my Global.asax routing area:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "AllPayments",
        "payment/receipt/{username}",
        new { controller = "Payment", action = "AllPayments" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "IndividualPayment",
        "payment/receipt/{username}/{id}",
        new { controller = "Payment", action = "SinglePayment" }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

This how my images are declared in my _Layout.cshtml file:

```
<img src="../../Content/SiteImages/banner1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
<img src="../../Content/SiteImages/banner2.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
<img src="../../Content/SiteImages/banner3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

Where normally my images would `src` to

`www.foo.com/Content/SiteImages/logo.png`,

in this particular view, they are changed to

```
www.foo.com/payment/Content/SiteImages/logo.png
```

How can I fix this issue? What is causing my images src to change in this particular view?

Comment: What does the <img> tag look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are viewing a specific payment, you are one step deeper into the url.

Where

```
<img src="../../Content/SiteImages/banner1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

would work on the AllPayments page, you need

```
<img src="../../../Content/SiteImages/banner1.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
```

on the individual payment page.

Comment: I think using `Url.Content` would be the better, future proof way. Thanks for making me realize I had forgotten to use this.